# Notepad - replaces returns with line breaks when stripping format from text

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, html, linebreaks

I've used Notepad for years to strip out formatting from Word or web pages when using that text in html. Recently, the default behaviour (using returns between paragraphs) has changed, and now Notepad uses line breaks (br) between paragraphs. I now have to replace all the br with p tags. I can't find out why this is happening, or how to stop it.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Could you please add a bit more information, such as what browser you are copying from or what version of Word. Does this happen with some documents/web pages or all? Have you changed anything recently, e.g updated software, installed something new?